# Can't optimize a nested query using indexes

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization, subquery

There are two tables containing hundreds of thousands of records: `client` and `task`. It's necessary to query the following:

```
SELECT
  id,
  (SELECT status
   FROM task t
   WHERE t.client_id = c.id AND t.status != 2
   ORDER BY task_date DESC
   LIMIT 1) AS task_status
FROM client c;
```

This query takes about five minutes, which is unacceptable. So, I tried to create indexes in the following ways:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY some_name_idx
  ON task (status, client_id);
```

> execution: 1m 1s 475ms, fetching: 21ms

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY some_name_idx
  ON task (status, client_id, task_date DESC);
```

> execution: 1m 3s 269ms, fetching: 34ms

As you can see, the result is not impressive. Another one approach isn't correct, but it helped to achieve the expected result:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY some_name_idx
  ON task (client_id, task_date DESC)
  WHERE status != 2;
```

> execution: 229ms, fetching: 36ms

I can't use this version because similar subqueries used in our system will get an incorrect result because of `WHERE status != 2` clause, which specific only for a single query.

I would be grateful for help on query optimization in such cases.

Thanks.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plans generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please (preserving the indention), [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Try an index `ON task (client_id, task_date DESC, status)`

Answer (score 1):

Your best simple index is probably going to be on `(client_id, task_date, status)`.  client_id should go first, because it is the only one used with an equality operator.  Including `status` will only help for index-only scans, so it depends on how well vacuumed `task` is and your version of PostgreSQL.

The partial index will not lead to incorrect results.  Queries that cannot correctly use the partial index, will not use it.  So if `WHERE status != 2` is the most commonly queried case, or the most time-sensitive one, go ahead and make the partial index.